# Asp.Net C# DllImport problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, dllimport

I want to import DLL file in my web site project. I have dll file "my.dll" in folder C:\DLLDir and I'm using the code :

```
[DllImport("C:\\DLLDir\\my.dll", EntryPoint = "Out32")]
```

This works ok. But I want to use relative path (web site root path) . I'm trying to put "my.dll" in "bin" or root folder and I'm using the code :

```
   [DllImport("my.dll", EntryPoint = "Out32")]
```

but I'm getting the error: Unable to load DLL 'my.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it want the absolute path to the dll. Server.MapPath should do the trick for you

Comment: Server.MapPath gives you the paths relative to you web directory location. So if you have the absolute path already it won't make any difference.

Comment: But Server.MapPath will allow the OP to use a relative path to the DLL, but pass in an absolute path to DLLImport.

Comment: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33238643/aspnet-and-dllimport.aspx  You can put your DLL to system32 or you fix your path variable

Comment: Does my.dll have any dependencies?  If so have you copied those dependencies to the websites bin directory also?

Comment: @Aaron putting them in the bin doesn't work.  The problem is that he needs to put the unmanaged DLL into C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\xxxx.  There is no easy way to do this because the path is dynamically generated.  The easiest way is to just put the dll into some known path or update the path variable

Comment: @Harvey - I'm not a interop guru by any means however, I created a c# web app and a simple C++ dll with an exported function.  I copied the c++ dll to the web applications bin directory and I'm able to call the exported function just fine using DllImport with out using the fully qualified path or updating the path environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may want to check out the following SO question first (since it's related to your case):

[DllImport failed to locate DLL even though it is in the PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294080/dllimport-failed-to-locate-dll-even-though-it-is-in-the-path)

As other people has suggested, check the `PATH` environment variable to make sure that `C:\DLLDir\` is there. You can read more about how to do configure your environment variables [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Check out this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/14dc569b-b761-4021-b3a7-559138daaf71/) as well (seems like there was an issue with dependencies).

If it's a COM DLL you're importing then it might also requires to be registered first on a target machine (although I'm not sure if this is needed). [Read more here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Either you did not copy my.dll to Bin folder where it should be loaded.
Using Process Explorer ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will likley show where it tries to load this file from.

EDIT: thanks to volpav for reminding that it is unmanaged DLL - ignore manged portion...
...assembly have some other dependencies.
Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx that details investiagtion of such failures (search for "assembly load fussion log" for more links).

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with Fusion since it's unmanaged DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Properties/Build` tab, and set Platform target to `x86`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the DLL has to be on your path (if not absolute).  And what will likely surprize you is that CWD is not on your path unless you specifically add "." in your PATH variable.