# Calling Dll works in windows application but not in web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am using below dll calling in windows application .cs file below..

SBXPCDLL.cs File:

```
[DllImport("SBXPCDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
static extern byte _ConnectTcpip(Int32 dwMachineNumber, ref IntPtr lpszIPAddress, Int32 dwPortNumber, Int32 dwPassWord);

public static bool ConnectTcpip(Int32 dwMachineNumber, string lpszIPAddress, Int32 dwPortNumber, Int32 dwPassWord)
{
    if (lpszIPAddress == null)
        return false;

    IntPtr string_in = Marshal.StringToBSTR(lpszIPAddress);
    try
    {
        byte ret = _ConnectTcpip(dwMachineNumber, ref string_in, dwPortNumber, dwPassWord);
        return ret > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeBSTR(string_in);
    }
}
```

Window file:

```
 if (SBXPCDLL.ConnectTcpip(Program.gMachineNumber, lpszIPAddress, Convert.ToInt32(txtPortNo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtPassword.Text)))
      {
//Connected
      }
```

Same Format i use in web application in asp.net.. It not connected but in sometime it connected for one time only...Anybody could help us..

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4637302/1271037

Comment: dll loaded successfully but my issue not that...same code i use both windows & web.. Device connected in windows but not in web...

Comment: I am not sure but may be there is a problem in access rights...
Because Asp.net web app run on iis with IIS User access rights. So try to impersonate other windows user.