# converting old asp code to asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp-classic

Hi i have this dll from an old project that the dll is uses to login but uppon adding the DLL on reference it give's me `a reference "AppUser.dll" can't be added, Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.` 
here's the old code using the Dll its written in asp

```
'/ Create AppUser Object
    set MyUser =Server.CreateObject("AppUser.User") 
    MyUser.UserName=Request.Form("UserName")            'set this first - CANNOT BE OMITTED
    Response.Write(MyUser)


if MyUser.Login("WebApps","AppUsers",Request.Form("UserName"),Request.Form("Password"))=false then

    Session("NumAttempts") = Session("NumAttempts") + 1
        if Application("NumAttempts") = 0 then
```

so oppon researching i found that i can use DLL import in order to import.

Here's what i tryed

```
[DllImport("AppUser.User", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool Login(string webapps, String appuser, String username,string password);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        protected void btnLogin_ServerClick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = txtUser.Value;
          bool iscorrect = Login("WebApps", "AppUsers", txtUser.Value, txtpassword.Value);
          if (iscorrect == true)
          {
              Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
          }
          else
          {

          }
        }
```

but i get

```
An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in WebApps.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'AppUser.User': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

i also try this   `[DllImport(@"C:\**\****\Documents\projects\WebApps\WebApps\bin\AppUser.User", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`
but get

```
An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in WebApps.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'C:\Users\nx011116\Documents\projects\WebApps\WebApps\bin\AppUser.User': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Can i use that old dll in my new project because the dencryption of password on login is on that dll and that dll is only what we have to use in log in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.Net C# DllImport problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637302/asp-net-c-sharp-dllimport-problem)

Comment: Can you clear us about your problem? or what you need to know?

Comment: converting the first code from classic asp to asp.net

Comment: `AspCompat="true"` allows you to use COM objects in an aspx page.  You might find it much quicker to rewrite your code as VB.net though, it would allow you to make minimal changes to your VBScript. 
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interviews/show/179/what-does-aspcompattrue-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it